# how do i SQL specific items from a column (php)

Tags: php

```
<?php
    mysql_connect('localhost', 'admin', '') or die (mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("elia_internal") or die (mysql_error());

    $query = "SELECT * FROM information GROUP BY Karori ";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    print"<tr><td>".$row['Agent']."</td><td>".$row['Address']."</td><td>".$row['Suburb']."</td><td>".$row['Bedrooms']."</td><td>".$row['Bathrooms']."</td><td>".$row['Price']."</td>";
    }
```

?>

I am trying to SQL specific items from columns from my database for example im trying to pull up all houses listed in the suburb Karori. the column is Suburb and there are 5 different suburbs in the column. how do i get the php to show JUST the houses listed in Karori and not the others.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM information WHERE Suburb='Karori'` : Sorry this was too trivial to be put up as an answer

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky Well, _someone_ has to answer it. Unless you think the question is so simple it should be closed.

Comment: I did answer it for them and just put up a note at the end. I didn't vote for this question to be closed either. I just don't want to take any credit for it.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM information where suburb="karori" GROUP BY Karori ";
```

Comment: Group BY **VALUE** doesn't work and is useless in this case even if it worked